# Nuxt3 Connection to Postgresql Database with pg library

Tags: postgresql, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using Nuxt3 for VueJs with an external Postgresql database.
In my component.vue:

```
<script>
import { Client } from 'pg'
 
const client = new Client({
  host: 'my.database-server.com',
  port: 5334,
  database: 'database-name',
  user: 'database-user',
  password: 'secretpassword!!',
})

await client.connect()

const queryResult = await client.query('SELECT * FROM public.signal')
res.value = queryResult.rows;
console.log('Query result:', res.value);
await client.end();
</ script>
<template>
<div>{{res}}</div>
</template>
```

The result of the query is rightfully being displayed in the console log but do not show up in the application.
An error 500 "Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null" appears instead.
This error appears even if I only import {Client} from "pg";
It seems that the "pg" library is bugging but I'm not sure.
Does anyone knows what is going on?

I'm trying to display the results queried from a database into my Nuxt3 application. I try to move the code somewhere else (in /plugins or /utils folder without much success).

Comment: move database query logic to server routes and useFetch library to fetch the data